# Issue with getting correct highest average speed

Tags: ruby

I try to do this task:[codewars kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/speed-control/ruby)

> Description:
>
> In John's car the GPS records every s seconds the distance travelled
>   from an origin (distances are measured in an arbitrary but consistent
>   unit). For example, below is part of a record with s = 15:
>
> x = [0.0, 0.19, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25] The
>   sections are:
>
> 0.0-0.19, 0.19-0.5, 0.5-0.75, 0.75-1.0, 1.0-1.25, 1.25-1.50, 1.5-1.75, 1.75-2.0, 2.0-2.25 We can calculate John's average hourly speed on every section and we get:
>
> [45.6, 74.4, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0] Given s and x
>   the task is to return as an integer the floor of the maximum average
>   speed per hour obtained on the sections of x. If x length is less than
>   or equal to 1 return 0: the car didn't move.
>
> Example:
>
> with the above data your function gps(x, s)should return 74

My code:

```
def gps(s, x)
  i = 0
  speed = 0
  max = 0
  0 if x.length <= 1
  while i < x.length - 2
    speed = get_speed(x[i].to_f, x[i + 1].to_f, s)
    max = speed if speed > max
    i += 1
  end
  print max.floor
end

def get_speed(a, b, s)
  ((b - a).abs * ((60 / s) * 60))
end
```

Problem is with passing some tests.

Tests:
`gps(20, [0.0, 0.23, 0.46, 0.69, 0.92, 1.15, 1.38, 1.61]) result: 41` - correct
`gps(12, [0.0, 0.11, 0.22, 0.33, 0.44, 0.65, 1.08, 1.26, 1.68, 1.89, 2.1, 2.31, 2.52, 3.25]) result: 77` - incorrect, should be 219.

I don't have idea where I do wrong. Could someone give some hint to resolve problem?

Comment: Can you post the question here?

Comment: @Pramod post updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@mcfinnigan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38565630/2988) correctly identifies the immediate mistake in your code, but the *real* underlying cause is that you are not writing idiomatic Ruby. If you were writing idiomatic Ruby (instead of FORTRAN in Ruby syntax, as you are doing), then you would use iterators instead of manually fiddling with loop indices and the problem wouldn't even arise in the first place. Something like this:

```
def gps(interval, measurements)
  compute_result(interval, measurements).tap(&method(:print))
end

private

def compute_result(interval, measurements)
  return 0 if measurements.length <= 1
  hourly_speed(max_distance(*distances(*measurements)), interval)
end

def distances(*measurements)
  measurements.
    each_cons(2).       # iterate over all consecutive pairs
    map {|a, b| b - a } # transform to list of distances travelled
end

def max_distance(*distances)
  distances.max
end

def hourly_speed(distance, time_in_seconds)
  seconds_per_hour = 60.0 * 60
  (distance * seconds_per_hour / time_in_seconds).floor
end
```

As you see, there are no loops, no indices, no loop conditions, in fact, apart from the edgecase of an empty measurements array, there are no conditions at all, and so there are no conditions, indices, loops etc. to get wrong.

The problem is broken down into smaller subproblems that can be tested and debugged individually. Every method returns a value (instead of just printing to the console), which makes it possible to easily test it automatically (and also to reuse it in other methods).

Comment: This is a nice solution.

Comment: Could you explain me why do you notate, that some parameters are optional?

Comment: @ŁukaszKorol: There are no optional parameters in my code.

Comment: What does mean * before name of parameters?

Answer (score 2):

```
while i < x.length - 2
```

This appears to be the issue.  A classic off-by-one error; you are not considering the final element in your array.

Change your condition to

```
while i < x.length - 1
```

and your bug goes away.

Comment: I don't agree with you, because I use x.length -2 to get x[i+1]. In your case i+1 is out range of array.

Comment: I promise you it isn't.  Your array is length 14, i never exceeds 12.

Comment: Ok I agree with you, but still program doesn't pass all tests.

Comment: @ŁukaszKorol: there's another obvious problem in that your line 5 doesn't do anything. It evaluates to `0` if the array length is less than 1 and evaluates to `nil` otherwise, but you are not doing anything with that value, you are not returning it, not storing it, not passing it anywhere else.